# Duplicating existing site to create a testing environment

Tags: ee2

Probably this question already answered somewhere, but i was unable to find it out. I have a Expression Engine v2.1.0 and i want to duplicate site on another hosting.

1. Can i simply move it to another hosting through FTP, copy a database, replace path and start working on it?
2. The main question would license key be lost on original site (or whatever license EE have)? Is there are any problems with license when creating duplicate on another hosting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well for your first question, Yes you can just copy the site through FTP, upload database, change path and start working. (Only thing you should care about is your PHP version for new server. Make sure you have PHP 5 instead of PHP 7. Reason behind this is EE2 is not compatible with PHP7)

For your second question, Yes you can have as many test environment server as you want. You not need to buy any extra license for that.

You will find more information about this at:

https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/223922
https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/106247/test-site-environment#558093